How can I match height of buttons dynamically withrespect to text?
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Expanded Buttons'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: [
                ExpandedButton(text: 'Button 1'),
                ExpandedButton(text: 'Button 2'),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                ExpandedButton(
                    text: 'Button 3' +
                        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed dictum eros ac ante consectetur convallis. Nullam malesuada, lorem sed consectetur scelerisque, lectus velit convallis ex, id molestie lectus lorem at nisi. Sed id risus et nisi lacinia eleifend. Maecenas fermentum nec purus ac consequat. Vestibulum posuere,'),
                ExpandedButton(text: 'Button 4'),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                ExpandedButton(text: 'Button 5'),
                ExpandedButton(text: 'Button 6'),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                ExpandedButton(text: 'Button 7'),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ExpandedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;

  const ExpandedButton({Key? key, required this.text}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // Add your onPressed logic here
          },
          child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0), child: Text(text)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Above, you can see that the height of button 3 is different because of the content from all the other buttons. How can I apply that same height to all the remaining buttons?
Note: I don't want to assign a fixed height; rather, I want it to adjust according to the content.
I'm beginner in Flutter.
This is the image, I wanted to have all buttons of same size with respect to button 3 and adjust according to the content, if the content is changed:


Get length of longest button's text in your list, and apply that length as height to every button. Here is code for find height...
double maxHeight = buttonTexts
.map((text) => TextPainter(
text: TextSpan(text: text, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
)..layout())
.map((tp) => tp.height)
.reduce((maxHeight, height) => maxHeight > height ? maxHeight : height);

If you want to display the buttons in a grid style then use the GridView widget. It makes sure to assign the same height to all of its children.

First I think you need to find the longest text by counting the number of characters
Then using TextPainter to measure text size for the longest text, need to provide text style & maxWidth (e.g in your case maxWidth = screenWidth/2 - padding) of the text, so you can get the height of this longest text.
double _measureTextSize(double maxWidth, TextStyle textStyle) {
  final textSpan = TextSpan(
    text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit',
    style: textStyle,
  );
  final textPainter = TextPainter(text: textSpan, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
  textPainter.layout(maxWidth: maxWidth);
  return textPainter.height;
}

Now you have the max height, let's set it to all your buttons (remember to add some padding for the buttons since this is only the height of the text).
